# kubernetes pod: no url specified when running curl through image

Tags: docker, curl, kubernetes

I have an image whose `ENTRYPOINT` is the following:

```
TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-identity-token)

curl -s -XGET -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
```

And here is my `container` `spec` within a `Job` definition that invokes the above image:

```
    spec:
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      containers:
      - name:  pre-upgrade-job
        image: "my-image:0.0.1"
        args: ["https://some-url"]
```

However, invocation fails with:

```
➢  k logs -f my-pod
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

**edit**: Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-identity-token)

echo $1

curl -s -XGET -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
```

Comment: how curl supose to see your URL args if you not write it in the command ?

Comment: aren't the `args` appended to the image's `ENTRYPOINT` ?

Comment: not automatically you need to use `curl -s -XGET -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" $MYARGS` and you specify the args not correctly. see https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/

Comment: is `MYARGS` a reserved keyword for this purpose?

Comment: anyway this does not seem to be the case: > The command and arguments that you define in the configuration file override the default command and arguments provided by the container image. If you define args, but do not define a command, the default command is used with your new arguments. Taken from here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/

Comment: Can you include the actual Dockerfile in the question?  Is that a separate script, or have you written that fragment directly into the Dockerfile?

Comment: @DavidMaze pls check my update

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it turns out it was en escaping issue.

The following worked

```
spec:
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
  containers:
  - name:  pre-upgrade-job
    image: "my-image:0.0.1"
    args: 
     - "https://some-url"
```